# Classifying Module over commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

We have structure theorem for finitely-generated modules over a PID, what about finitely-generated modules over some general commutative rings?

A paper that I read said that it is unlikely to have such a theorem, but he didn't mention why.

Comment: Only finitely generated, right? A similar theorem holds for finitely generated modules over Dedekind domains. A general result is impossible I'd say.

Comment: @Paul K corrected. Yep, only finitely-generated. Why would you say it is impossible?

Comment: @icefire112233 informally speaking, classification questions with few hypothesis are *very* hard: if there are no restrictions whatsoever, the objects can get "as complicated as possible" and we admit all sorts of pathological borderline cases

Comment: @guidoar Certainly, I agree with whatever you have said. It's just that so far I've only encountered Modules over PIDs, there weren't really any examples which are like "see, the classifications of these modules over rings are so messy, so a general theorem is unlikely to exist".

Comment: Indeed, sometimes we see in class just the nice examples; but one should ponder what hypothesis are letting us do what we do. In this case, factorization of elements plays a central role in the whole decomposition; this is quite far from the situation for a general ring (rings could fail to have unique factorizations, may contain zero divisors, they could also be non commutative so now one has to disinguish between right and left ideals, etc.)

Comment: (cont.) As Paul pointed out, Dedekind domains are in a way a generalization of PIDs/UFDs in which instead of factoring elements intro primes, we factor ideals into products of primes. Having a similarly-spirited factorization, we can obtain a similar classification result.